# Time testing problem for sorting methods using random numbers and arrays

Tags: java, random, timing, insertion-sort

I have working code for sort methods with time analysis code in the end, but can't figure out where to put the random number or array generator code for the sort methods. I get errors each time I try, hopefully someone can show me how it looks when the random method is called instead of the default assign. Also, is the timing part done right? It doesn't seem like it should take that long, when I run I get something like 69391841667800 nanoseconds.

```
public class InsertSort {
private int[] arr;
public InsertSort(int[] array) {
arr = array;
}
private boolean more(int value1, int value2)
{
return value1 > value2;
}
public void sort()
{
int size = arr.length;
int temp,j;
for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
{temp=arr[i];
for(j=i; j>0 && more(arr[j-1], temp); j--)
{
arr[j]=arr[j-1];
}
arr[j]=temp;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int[] array = {9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5};
InsertSort bs = new InsertSort(array);
bs.sort();
for(int i=0;i<array.length ;i++)
{
System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
long endTime = System.nanoTime(); //Current system Time at end

long startTime = 0;
long duration = (endTime - startTime); //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.

System.out.print(duration);
}
}
```

This is my code for random number generator

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Random {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(generateRandomList(5, 1, 10));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> generateRandomList( int size, int min, int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        int n = (int)(Math.random() * (max-min))+min;
        list.add(n);
    }
    return list;
}

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the first code block properly.

Comment: What errors do you get? We can't help you if you don't show what the issue is

Comment: Turing not sure what you mean, I used the insert code feature here.

Comment: Kevin, basically I am not sure how to insert the random method into the insert method. I am supposed to test for timing of sorting methods for random number and array generators. When I try, I get errors such as - 

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
  QualifiedName
 - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token

at System.out.print(duration);

Comment: Question [re-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67767398/522444) and without formatting improvement

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
int[] array = {9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5};
```

in your first main method with call to `generateRandomList` like this

```
int[] array = Random.generateRandomList(5, 1, 10);
```

If you are not using IDE you may need tonadd you Random class to import section of your main class.

And measuring execution time for java code is **very** non-trivial. Please check the following link for more information https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

Comment: I tried by the I get the error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to int[]

Comment: @JavaNub you need to change `generateRandomList` to return array of numbers or change `InsertSort` to accept list instead of array

Comment: I tried changing generateRandomList to this but still get same error (sorry I cannot make it code format in comments) -

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Random {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(generateRandomList(5, 1, 10));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> generateRandomList( int size, int min, int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array;
    array = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        int n = (int)(Math.random() * (max-min))+min;
        array.add(n);
    }
    return array;
}

}

Comment: To change InsertSort to accept list instead of array, would I just change every "array" to "list" in that class?

Comment: Yes, and usually lists are easier to deal with then arrays

Comment: I tried changing every "array" to "list" in the InsertSort class , and presuming I have to change from arraylist to list in the Random class, but then  when I do so for the Random class I get the error "Cannot instantiate the type List", and still get the same error in the timing code "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to int[]"